# close form before click on X button with javascript or another way

Tags: javascript, html

i would to hide the form of login when i click on X button.
What is the better way to do this ?

```
<div id="vibe_bp_login" class="active" style="display: block;">
<a class="boxclose" id="boxclose"></a>
<div class="widget vibe-bp-login">              

<form name="login-form" id="vbp-login-form" class="standard-form" action="https://dentaldigit.com/wp-login.php" method="post">
 <label>Username<br>
 <input type="text" name="log" id="side-user-login" class="input" tabindex="1" value=""></label>

  <label>Password <a href="https://dentaldigit.com/wp-login.php?action=lostpassword&amp;redirect_to=https://dentaldigit.com/" tabindex="5" class="tip" title="" data-original-title="Forgot Password"><i     class="icon-question"></i></a><br>
   <input type="password" tabindex="2" name="pwd" id="sidebar-user-pass" class="input" value=""></label>

   <p class=""><label><input name="rememberme" tabindex="3" type="checkbox" id="sidebar-rememberme" value="forever">Remember Me</label></p>

   <input type="submit" name="user-submit" id="sidebar-wp-submit" value="Log In" tabindex="100">
   <input type="hidden" name="user-cookie" value="1">
   <a href="https://dentaldigit.com/register/" class="vbpregister" title="Create an account" tabindex="5">Registrati</a>                        </form>
        </div>
    </div>
```

i would use

```
<a class="boxclose" id="boxclose"></a> to close the form when i clickin on it
```

thanks

Comment: You can add a class on click of `X` which will set `display:none`

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#boxclose").click(function(e){ //on the button click.
  e.preventDefault();
  $("#vbp-login-form").hide();//this will be disappeared.
    });
```

This shall help you.

Comment: hi, thanks for code. i'm trying but i don't undestand what i wrong ... i insert the code here : http://jsfiddle.net/jzn82/1074/, but the form don't disappear  on click

Answer (score 0):

If you open the fiddle and check the console, you will see an error:

> 'TypeError: $(...) is null'

Maybe that is because jQuery is not loaded.

Does this updated fiddle do what you are looking for? I've added `$(document).ready` to wait until the DOM is loaded.

http://jsfiddle.net/jzn82/1086/